# How to implement a zero corssing detection method in simulink

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

I have a frequency modulated signal.

In matlab I am using the following simple code for zero crossing detection.
Here "x" is the input bits signal.
"m" is the modulated signal.

```
zerorate = [];
start = 1;

for j=length(m)/length(x):length(m)/length(x):length(m)

    delta = round((length(m)/length(x))/5);  %Gaurd Interval

    data = m(start + delta:j);
%     data = m(start:j);
    y = sum(abs(diff(data>0)))/length(data);
    zerorate = [zerorate y];
    start = j;
end

mn = zerorate>mean(zerorate);
```

Now I would like to implement the same in Simulink. Can I do zero crossing detection and detect the bits in Simulink ? Can someone guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to split your zero crossing block into two functional parts, one for deciding if the slope is positive or negative and another part for deciding if the signal is close to zero.

For the first part, route your signal to a differentiating block followed by a comparison block that checks if the current value is greater or smaller than zero.

For the second part, route your signal to a block that builds the absolute signal value followed by a comparison block that checks if the signal value equals zero (or is smaller than some tiny value).

Take the two resulting signals and feed them into an AND block which tells you, when both conditions are met and you have detected a zero crossing